# Selenium does not always recognize when an element is removed from the DOM

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am having an issue using chrome 56 with chromedriver 2.27 on mac 10.12.3, though I have tried several different versions of the driver and several different versions of the browser, and had the same issue. In the UI, I can see very clearly that a blocking layer has cleared, but selenium still thinks it has not. After waiting for the blocking layer to clear (just looking at the browser), if I capture the results of driver.getPageSource(), I get the 'old' page source, not the new page source (with the blocking layer removed). When i view the old page source as an html doc, I can see the blocking layer. When I view a screen shot taken when the test ends, there is clearly no blocking layer, and a manual inspection of the DOM shows that the element has been removed. Somehow selenium seems to be caching the old page source and not recognizing when an element has been removed from the DOM. I can't seem to force it to refresh the cached(?) html without completely reloading the page. I want to avoid re-loadng the page, because that invalidates a test of whether a blocking layer is being dropped correctly.

I have tried getting some information from with the blocking layer element (using something benign like element.isDisplayed(), or element.getLocation()), and these still seem to behave as if the element were still present.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, what is your goal, if I may ask? Is it to verify that something on the page isn't present? What do you mean by blocking layer, like a pop-up , modal or frame appearing for a set period of time? Are you using a profile with chrome? Because webdriver always starts fresh on default; I doubt it; it has cached something, it is more likely that you are capturing the getPageSource a tad too early perhaps. I'll put my money on not selecting the element  in a unique way or not waiting properly for it to disappear. I think, it will be a great help if you can post some HTML  code :)

Comment: that the element I am trying to click was not clickable, because there was something blocking it, even though the blocking element has actually been dropped from the DOM.  That blocking element is this…

<div class="gwt-PopupPanelGlass" style=“etc…”></div>

I loop for about a minute, checking every second to see if this glass-panel element is still present (‘driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@class='gwt-PopupPanelGlass’]”).  Most times, selenium tells me that the element is gone, and I can proceed without issue.  (continues)

Comment: However, sometimes selenium thinks this glass panel element is still on the page.  However, while the test is looping, I can inspect the DOM manually (look at the html in a web inspector), and I can see that the glass panel element is no longer present.  Yet repeatedly, when selenium checks for the element, it still finds it.  If I run driver.getPageSource() at this point, the result is the page source with the blocking layer element, but both the DOM and a visual inspection show that the element is in fact not present. (end comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to click the item irrespective of the status of *blocking layer*, you can use inline javascript to click an element. Sample code in below.

```
    try {
            e.click();
        } catch (org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException E1) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", e.findElements(By.xpath(".//a")).get(0));
        }
```

Comment: That seems to do it, thanks.  It seems to just barrel ahead with the click, regardless of whether selenium thinks the element is visible or not. One slight revision...   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElementByXpath("my_xPath_here")));

Comment: Thanks. I encounter this situation often for some of my web projects. Mostly, it is transparent floating menu layer, or a item hidden using css tweak which blocks the click operation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue running Selenium test with GWT popup panel.

Sometimes the animation won't finish, the popup and the glass behind stay on the DOM.

When that happen, I tried to remove from the dom these 2 elements, but got weird results (other elements from the dom were removed instead !!?).

At the end I implemented these functions that hide these 2 elements and change the className so that they won't bother us anymore (see code below)

waitForPopupOpeningAnimationFinished() : is to be launched after a click that is supposed to open a popup

waitForPopupClosingAnimationFinished() : is to be launched after a click on a popup button should close the popup

```
    // 200 is the animation time of the popup, we wait a lot more, see com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel.ANIMATION_DURATION
public static final int POPUP_ANIMATION_WAIT_TIME = 300;
public static final String CLASS_GWT_DIALOG_BOX = "gwt-DialogBox";
public static final String X_POPUP = "//div[@class='" + CLASS_GWT_DIALOG_BOX + "']";
public static final By BY_POPUP = By.xpath(X_POPUP);

public static final String X_POPUP_TOTALLY_OPENED_LOCATOR = "//div[contains(@class, '" + CLASS_GWT_DIALOG_BOX + "') and contains(@style, 'clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);')]";
public static final By BY_POPUP_TOTALLY_OPENED_LOCATOR = By.xpath(X_POPUP_TOTALLY_OPENED_LOCATOR);
private static final String CLASS_GWT_POPUP_PANEL_GLASS = "gwt-PopupPanelGlass";
private static final By BY_GLASS_PANEL = By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, '" + CLASS_GWT_POPUP_PANEL_GLASS + "')]");


    public void waitForPopupOpeningAnimationFinished() {
    LOGGER.info("waitForPopupOpeningAnimationFinished");
    try {
        waiter.withTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(POPUP_ANIMATION_WAIT_TIME)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(BY_POPUP_TOTALLY_OPENED_LOCATOR));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Forcing popup to be visible");
        try {
            js.executeScript("var elementsToBeRemoved = document.getElementsByClassName('" + CLASS_GWT_DIALOG_BOX + "');" //
                    + "if(elementsToBeRemoved.length>0){" //
                    + "elementsToBeRemoved[0].style.overflow='visible';" //
                    + "elementsToBeRemoved[0].style.clip='rect(auto,auto,auto,auto)';" //
                    + "}");
        } catch (JavascriptException e2) {
            LOGGER.warn("Could not find popup to force to be open", e2.getCause());
        }
    }
}

    public void waitForPopupClosingAnimationFinished() {
    try {
        LOGGER.info("waitForPopupClosingAnimationFinished");
        waiter.withTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(POPUP_ANIMATION_WAIT_TIME)).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(BY_POPUP));
        waiter.withTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(POPUP_ANIMATION_WAIT_TIME)).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(BY_GLASS_PANEL));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Waiting for popup closing did not work as expected, forcing it");
        javascriptRemovalOfElementByClassName(CLASS_GWT_DIALOG_BOX);
        javascriptRemovalOfElementByClassName(CLASS_GWT_POPUP_PANEL_GLASS);
    }
}

    private void javascriptRemovalOfElementByClassName(String className) {
    LOGGER.info("javascriptRemovalOfElementByClassName : {}", className);
    try {
        js.executeScript("var elementsToBeRemoved = document.getElementsByClassName('" + className + "');" //
                + "if(elementsToBeRemoved.length>0){" //
                + "elementsToBeRemoved[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';" //
                + "elementsToBeRemoved[0].style.display = 'none';" //
                + "elementsToBeRemoved[0].className='shouldHaveBeenRemovedFromDom';" //
                + "}");
        LOGGER.info("Successfully removal of element with class {}", className);
    } catch (JavascriptException jse) {
        LOGGER.info("Apparently element with class {}} does not exists, we are good to go : {}", className, jse.toString());
    }
}

    public void waitForPopupClosingAnimationFinished() {
    try {
        LOGGER.info("waitForPopupClosingAnimationFinished");
        waiter.withTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(POPUP_ANIMATION_WAIT_TIME)).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(BY_POPUP));
        waiter.withTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(POPUP_ANIMATION_WAIT_TIME)).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(BY_GLASS_PANEL));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Waiting for popup closing did not work as expected, forcing it");
        javascriptRemovalOfElementByClassName(CLASS_GWT_DIALOG_BOX);
        javascriptRemovalOfElementByClassName(CLASS_GWT_POPUP_PANEL_GLASS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same kind of issue with expanding/collapsing TreeNode animation so I implemented the below functions to be launched after a node expand/collapse:

```
    private static final String X_EXPANDING_TREE_NODE =
"//div[contains(@role, 'treeitem') and @aria-expanded='true']/div[contains(@style, 'overflow: hidden;') and contains(@style, 'height:') and contains(@style, 'position: relative;')]/div[contains(@style, 'top:') and contains(@style, 'position: relative;')]";
private static final By BY_EXPANDING_TREE_NODE = By.xpath(X_EXPANDING_TREE_NODE);

private static final String X_COLLAPSING_TREE_NODE =
"//div[contains(@role, 'treeitem') and @aria-expanded='false']/following:div[contains(@style, 'overflow: hidden;') and contains(@style, 'height:') and contains(@style, 'position: relative;')]/div[contains(@style, 'top:') and contains(@style, 'position: relative;')]";
private static final By BY_COLLAPSING_TREE_NODE = By.xpath(X_COLLAPSING_TREE_NODE);

/**
 * When a report tree node is expanding or collapsing is loading, we can see stuff like
 * <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 1px; position: relative;">
 * <div style="top: -122px; position: relative;">
 * <p>
 * We wait for it do disappear
 * <p>
 * or we force it to animation finished like this for expanding:
 *
 * <div style="overflow: hidden;">
 * <div style="">
 *
 * or we force it to animation finished like this for collapsing:
 *
 * <div style="overflow: hidden; display : none;">
 * <div style="">
 */
public void waitForTreeNodeExpandedAndCollapsed() {
    waitForTreeNodeExpanded();
    waitForTreeNodeCollapsed();
}

public void waitForTreeNodeExpanded(){
    waitForTreeNode(true);
}
public void waitForTreeNodeCollapsed(){
    waitForTreeNode(false);
}

private void waitForTreeNode(boolean expanding) {
    try {
        waiter.withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(expanding?BY_EXPANDING_TREE_NODE:BY_COLLAPSING_TREE_NODE ));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        boolean noJavascriptException = false;
        while (!noJavascriptException) { // While javascript throw error like InvalidStateError, we continue
            try {
                LOGGER.info("Waiting for tree expand or collapse did not work as expected, forcing it");
                js.executeScript("while(true){" //
                        + "var iterator = document.evaluate(\"" + (expanding?X_EXPANDING_TREE_NODE:X_COLLAPSING_TREE_NODE) + "\",document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null );" //
                        + "var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();" //
                        + "if(thisNode) {" //
                        + "thisNode.parentNode.style='overflow: hidden;" + (expanding?"":"display: none;")  + "';"//
                        + "thisNode.style='';"
                        + "thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();" //
                        + "}else {" //
                        + "break;" //
                        + "}" //
                        + "}");
                noJavascriptException = true;
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                LOGGER.info("Javascript pb", e2.getCause());
            }
        }
    }
}
```